# Windows Phone App Background HTTP Connectivity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on developing a non-VoIP Windows Phone application that needs to have a background HTTP connection to be notified when new messages are received.  I noticed for Windows Store apps, there is an example for ControlChannelTrigger that allows you to connect an HttpRequestMessage and will send a push notification to the app when data is returned by the http request.

Is there a similar concept that I can use for Windows Phone, because just using a Periodic Task really isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with Windows Phone. Once your app is not on the foreground anymore, there is no way for it to maintain a connection.

You should instead look into push notifications implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

There was a trick where you could use a background audio agent to maintain the connection but I don't think it's still doable. And is considered a very bad practice from both a developer and a user points of view.

So you should just go with the standard push notification thing linked above.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem with this approach is that it requires you to be able to modify the server to integrate with the push notification service.  My app connects to third party servers that we cannot modify.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is currently no other way if you want to show notifications when your app is not on the foreground anymore.